# Histogram Normalization Features

Tags: image-processing, histogram

I am confused how I extract features using histogram normalization. Maybe this sounds too silly but sorry about been silly I am just confused. I have normalized the image but how i represent it as a feature. Is it the histogram becomes the feature or is it the concept of HOG (histogram of Oriented Gradient). I am confused how I represent histogram as a features. Can I get some explanation on this please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *feature descriptor* may be defined as any property of a pattern that describes it in part or in full. When you extract the histogram of an image, you're extracting a few properties of the image that may be applied or exploited in various ways. For example, if you have a majority of the histogram population biased towards the darker side, you can conclude that the image is either filled with dark patterns or is not illuminated sufficiently. So the histogram itself is an effective feature descriptor.

To make histograms comparable, normalisation is usually necessary. For example, you may want to compare images of different sizes. In this case, the overall population of the histograms will be different for the two images. But once you normalise the histograms, they become comparable, which in turn makes the feature description effective and usable.

Comment: Thanks alot for clear explaination. One question, like i want to do image retrieval for my project. Images are of various scenes and places. I have normalized all the training set, and now I am left with feature extraction where I am stuck. What i am thinking to do for features is use the bins and dimension of the histogram and than use the KNN for re-trivial. Do you think that feature is correct. I cant use sift, etc due to project is on the concept of histogram.What could be my features any clue or help?

Comment: What kinds of places and scenes will you be covering? In the past, I've found that normalised histograms of hue and value in the HSV colour space are quite effective in identification of places.

Comment: Data set is made of buildings, forests, sea sides.. My only confusion is what will be my feature vector in using histogram. (Using HOG is good idea you think)..

Comment: HOG wouldn't be relevant in these cases, because it is useful for detecting objects with consistent edges and orientations. Just use the normalised histogram as the feature vector. The histogram is effectively a list of 256 values (populations of bins). Use this as a 256-length feature vector.

Comment: I see thanks thats helpful information. For 256 lenght vector, the number of count of pixels in each bins becomes the feature vectors. Did i get that correct.